# Redirect to a webpage after download is cancelled

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show a webpage once I have explicitly canceled a download from proceeding. But the webpage isn't loaded in such case.

I have tried using chrome.runtime.getURL();

```
chrome.downloads.cancel(downloadid,function(){
  return {redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL("mycustomewebpage.html")};
});
```

Once the download is canceled, I want to see my custom webpage explaining which file was canceled from downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after few tries I found what I had been doing incorrect here. So instead of window.open("mycustomewebpage.html") or  window.location = chrome.runtime.getURL("mycustomewebpage.html") inside chrome.downloads.cancel , I called it after cancel function (instead of calling inside it) and now I can see new html page being launched.

Answer (score 1):

Callback function is not supposed to return anything.

Try with:

```
chrome.downloads.cancel(downloadid, function() {
  window.location = chrome.runtime.getURL("mycustomewebpage.html");
});
```

Comment: If I add that then download proceeds instead of blocking. Cannot view redirected webpage even with this code.